# Django Template full width CSS

Tags: html, css, django, templates

i would like to put all of my Category elements side by side but for some reason i get two elemnts beside each-other and after that a new row starts and on the left i still got a lot of space...

**css**

```
.category {
    float: left;
    width: 40%;
    margin-right: 3.33333%;
    margin-bottom: 3.33333%;
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background: radial-gradient(white, white, whitesmoke);
    border-radius: 3%;

}

.categorycover {
    height: 100px;
    -webkit-box-reflect: below 8px -webkit-gradient(linear, right top, right bottom, from(transparent), to(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)));
}
```

**template**

```
{% block content %}
    {% for category in object_list %}
        <div>
            <span class="category">
                <img class="categorycover" src="/media/{{ category.cover }}">
                <h1>{{ category.title }}</h1>
                <p>{{ category.post_set.count }}Posted element(s)</p>
                <p>{{ category.description|readmore:10|linebreaksbr}}</p>
            </span>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

do i have to put a div container with 100% of the page width on it? Any hint would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I might offer an alternative approach. Leverage the power of Flexbox to get items to fit in a row nicely.

```
{% block content %}
    {% for category in object_list %}
        <div class="container">
            <span class="category">
                <img class="categorycover" src="/media/{{ category.cover }}">
                <h1>{{ category.title }}</h1>
                <p>{{ category.post_set.count }}Posted element(s)</p>
                <p>{{ category.description|readmore:10|linebreaksbr}}</p>
            </span>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Your styling can then look like:

```
.container{
display:flex;
flex-direction: row;
justify-content: space-around; #or space-evenly
}
.category{
    padding: 15px;
text-align: center;
box-sizing: border-box;
background: radial-gradient(white, white, whitesmoke);
border-radius: 3%;
}
```

The parent container flexbox stylings will take care of alignment for you as well as margin spacing. It works really nicely for aligning items in a div horizontally or vertically. See this article for further stylings you can play with: [A Complete Guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: This does not solve the issue. I try to explain currently i get only 2 elements per row, but i have space for at least 5-6 per row but the space on the right does not gets used...

Comment: Have you tried the css? This should appropriately align items on a single row if you have the space for it.